# Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments error

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments [build_c8wewmbxh7e7ovp9lqxsr05th$_run_closure2$_closure6@5261a942] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             16.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I need to clear this error

Answer (score 1):

It means "something" within `kotlinOptions { ... }` is invalid.

Unfortunately, with Groovy DSL you often get such not-too-helpful errors if you mess up the syntax. The only way to find out besides seeing the problem is commenting out and in things inside that closure to find where it breaks.

Besides that, I can highly recommend switching to Kotlin DSL instead. By now it is the default DSL, you immediately get type-safe build scripts, actually helpful error messages if you mess up the syntax like here, and an amazingly better IDE support if you use a good IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.